Using MIME to send myself a text and last two characters of body is missing
I have a job setup to run daily that will send me a text reminder.  The reminder is sent to me successfully, but not matter what I use for my "message" the last two characters are cut off.
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from dotenv import dotenv_values
import os

secrets = dotenv_values()

email = secrets['EMAIL']
password = secrets['EMAIL_PASSWORD']
recipient = secrets['RECIPIENT']
auth = (email, password)

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["Subject"] = "Chicken Alarm"
msg["From"] = email
msg["To"] = recipient

message = "It's chicken time"
msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(auth[0], auth[1])
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(auth[0], recipient, text)
server.quit()

What's going on that would be causing the last two characters to get cut off?

I notice you are using message in the call to MIMEText but running the message through as_string() before passing it as a parameter to sendmail. Could as_string be doing something that makes the value of text longer than message? (Encoding it, maybe?)

@padeso I'll take a look at that tomorrow.  The odd thing though is every version of message gets truncated no matter the length.  My first message was "Time to lock up the chickens" and that got truncated by 2 characters as well.

FWIW if I send this message to aiosmtpd the content is not truncated. Do you see the truncation in your email client?  If so, can you paste the "raw message" into the question?

@snakecharmerb In my email client it's not truncated, and I think I got it working last night.  I removed 'plain' from the MIMEText method and I think it's working now.  Will have to give it a try again tonight after work.
